# Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am running the following code using putty and the expected behaviour should be the following: when the thread responsible with the reading from a file has ended, the other thread responsible with the timer has to end too and reverse: if the thread responsible with the timer has ended, the other one has to end too. But i get this fatal error: `Server unexpectedly closed network connection` when there is one minute left. What i am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* global variables to check the state*/
int read = 0;
int timeLeft = 0;

void *readFromFile(void *myFile)
{

  int state;
  char *theFile;
  theFile = (char*) myFile;
  char question[100];
  char answer[100];
  state = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL );
  FILE *file = fopen(theFile, "r");
  if (file != NULL )
  {
    while (fgets(question, sizeof question, file) != NULL )
    {
      fputs(question, stdout);
      scanf("%s", &answer);
    }
    fclose(file);
    state = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL );
    printf("Done with questions!\n");
    read = 1;

  }
  else
  {
    perror(theFile);
  }
}

void displayTimeLeft(void *arg)
{
  int *time;
  int state;
  time = (int*) arg;
  int i;
  state = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL );
  for (i = time; i >= 0; i -= 60)
  {
    if (i / 60 != 0)
    {
      printf("You have %d %s left.\n", i / 60,
          (i / 60 > 1) ? "minutes" : "minute");
      sleep(60);
    }
    else
    {
      state = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL );
      printf("The time is over \n");
      timeLeft = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1;
  pthread_t thread2;
  char *file = "/home/osystems01/laura/test";
  int *time = 180;

  int ret1;
  int ret2;
  ret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, readFromFile, file);
  ret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, displayTimeLeft, time);

  printf("Main function after pthread_create\n");

  while (1)
  {
    if (read == 1)
    {

      pthread_cancel(thread2);
      pthread_cancel(thread1);
      break;
    }
    else if (timeLeft == 1)
    {

      pthread_cancel(thread1);
      pthread_cancel(thread2);
      break;
    }

  }

  printf("After the while loop!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The concurrent access to the variables `timeLeft` and `read` has to be protected. This can be done by using mutexes.

Comment: I suspect the the program is not the cause for the server shutting down the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I strongly doubt the server shuts down the connection established via putty because issues with your program.

However here are several issues with the program's code.

---

The ost critical issue is you are accessing the two global variable concurrently from two threads.

Concurrent access needs to be protected. To do so declare two mutexes like so:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex_read = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_time = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


void *readFromFile(void *myFile)
{
    ...

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex_read);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_lock(mutex_read) failed");
      }
    }

    read = 1;

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex_read);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex_read) failed");
      }
    }

    ...
}


void displayTimeLeft(void *arg)
{
    ...

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex_time);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_lock(mutex_time) failed");
      }
    }

    timeLeft= 1;

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex_time);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex_time) failed");
      }
    }

    ...

}

int main(void)
{
  ...

  while(1)
  {
    int bread = 0;
    int btimeLeft = 0;

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex_read);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_lock() failed");
      }
    }

    bread = (1 == read);

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex_read);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock() failed");
      }
    }

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_lock(mutex_time);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_lock() failed");
      }
    }

    btimeLeft = (1 == timeLEft);

    {
      int result = pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex_time);
      if (0 != result)
      {
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock() failed");
      }
    }

    if (bread == 1)
    {

      pthread_cancel(thread2);
      pthread_cancel(thread1);
      break;
    }
    else if (btimeLeft == 1)
    {

      pthread_cancel(thread1);
      pthread_cancel(thread2);
      break;
    }
  }  
  ...
```

For PThreads thr threas function needs to be declared as:

```
void * (*) (void *)
```

This isn't the case for `displayTimeLeft`

---

When scanning in a "string" one need to pass the address of the first element of the character array representing the string. So this

```
scanf("%s", &answer);
```

should be this

```
scanf("%s", &answer[0]);
```

or this

```
scanf("%s", answer);
```

---

The code misses the protoype for `sleep()`, so add

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Having done so the compiler detects a name clash between the system call `read()` and the global variable `read` declared by your code. This is not nice. Rename `read`to something like `readit`.

---

Last not least there is the issue mentioend by *[suspectus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827600/suspectus)* in his answer. You are misusing a pointer to an `int` to store some time value (`int * time = 180`). Do not do that.

To fix this do like so:

```
int main(void)
{
  ...
  int time = 180;
  ...
  ret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, displayTimeLeft, &time);
```

and in `displayTimeLeft` do:

```
 int time = *((int*) arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are initialising a pointer to the memory location 180.

```
int *time = 180;
```

What is needed is:

```
int time = 180;
...
...
ret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, displayTimeLeft, &time);
```

Comment: That's not all the OP then needs to change. You might also like to point the OP to how to adjust the code in `displayTimeLeft`, which will be broken after applying the adjustments you propose.

Comment: I have made the changes, but the result it's the same.